# State Diagram Confusion with Events

Tags: events, uml, diagram, state-diagram

I finished a state diagram in regards to an auction system and had it sent for feedback. I received a confusing feedback.

> "The stuff within the big blue thingie are actually events, not state
>   of the objects itself"

Here is the mentioned state diagram, can anyone help to elaborate as to what the feedback actually means? That big blue state should be a composite state with concurrent sub states, so I am not really sure what the feedback refers to.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition is correct. The feedback you got was bogus. However, it appears you are writing your events as guard conditions within square brackets. That is incorrect, as are the commas. A guard condition should be a Boolean expression, like [x > 0].

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Jim! I will make the necessary adjustments.